# mysql how to format subtime

Tags: mysql

I want to format the return value from subtime into the following format: HH:MM

```
SUBTIME('09:00:00', SEC_TO_TIME(30*60)), 
DATE_FORMAT(SUBTIME('09:00:00', SEC_TO_TIME(30*60)), '%H:%i')
```

first subtime returns me correct 08:30:00
but the one with date_format, returns me just NULL

Can you help me out plz?

Comment: What is the date value you want to add?

Comment: which date value do i want to add?
as a result there should be just 08:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use TIME_FORMAT and not DATE_FORMAT:

```
TIME_FORMAT(SUBTIME('09:00:00', SEC_TO_TIME(30*60)), '%H:%i')
```